# Django Python Script Doesn't Output Files

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I have a script that executes the following code through a Django view:

```
# generate dag file
        try:
            commandString = [
                'python',
                os.path.join('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50', userFolder, directory, 'condor_execute.py')
            ]
            subprocess.check_call(commandString,
                            stdout=open('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50/output2.txt', 'w'),
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        except Exception, e:
            open('/tmp/test_exception.txt', 'w').write(str(e))
            raise
```

What that is supposed to do is execute a Python file I have generated. If I run that exact command from the server's command prompt (i.e., `python /srv/nfsshare/transcode50/cogden/algorithms/condor_execute.py`), it works just fine and produces the needed files it's supposed to within that directory. However, if I run it from Django, it produces no error messages, produces the correct console output (a message that basically says "Created file blah at blah"), but produces no files whatsoever, when it normally generates two. I'm getting no permissions errors or anything and have ensured the directory is chmodded appropriately.

Comment: `subprocess.call` won't raise an exception, replace it with `subprocess.check_call` and see if an exception is raised.

Comment: I tried that, but still not getting any exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your process is never getting around to closing the file (as you can't do it explicitly as you have no reference to it - while run as a script - the interpreter would have stopped - but Django works different with loaded processes etc...) and it's not big enough to be flushed - try moving out your `open`.

```
with open('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50/output2.txt', 'w') as stdout:   
    subprocess.check_call(commandString, stdout=stdout, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Also, make sure that when you make changes to make sure the Django server is restarted/similar to make sure code is reloaded and changes are taken into effect.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of a resource that may teach me more about things like that? That was very helpful.

Comment: @coltonoscopy which particular part?

Comment: In particular, just how not closing stdout could have trickled down into not allowing the files within condor_execute to generate.

Comment: When data is written to a file, the OS normally buffers the data before writing it so it's of a size that's convenient for the disk to physically write before telling the disk to write it. The data is written when the buffer overflows, the file closes or is manually "flushed"... In CPython file objects when they go out of scope (their reference count reaches 0) are immediately closed - this is not the case for all implementations of Python. So if your file was kept alive, was never closed and never flushed, and never had enough data, then it'd stay blank.

Comment: Very useful knowledge; thank you for taking the time to explain! It's no wonder with open is so commonly advocated.

Comment: Hm, for some reason, it seems that it's no longer working? It only seemed to work just the very first time I tried it?

Comment: @coltonoscopy Interesting... did anything change between the attempts?

Comment: I changed code that was below the block which you suggested I edit, but to rule that out I commented out said code and functionally it is the same as having that new code (the files are no longer generating again).

Comment: @coltonoscopy well you might want to unaccept for the moment then... and make sure you've restarted the server (to make sure).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39864/discussion-between-coltonoscopy-and-jon-clements)